# how to configure .htc files to work on nginx

Tags: css, nginx, mime-types, ie8-compatibility-mode

I'm trying to run rounded corners on <= IE8 using border-radius.htc located [here](http://code.google.com/p/curved-corner/downloads/detail?name=border-radius.htc&can=2&q=).  I've run the URL to the .htc file in my browser, and I can view the code so my path is correct in the css file.  I'm using nginx to host my webpages.

Does anyone know how I can get this file to run so that the styling works in < IE9?  I've read some [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306231) about `MIME` types for .htc extensions, but I don't know what to do for nginx or even if `MIME` type is the issue.  If there is some other way to get the rounded corners without using an .htc file, I'm open to try that solution as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found the answer, [this solution](http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/wiki/ChangingServerMIMEType).  It's the 2nd post down on the thread.

*Comment by mjijackson@gmail.com, Oct 15, 2009*

***The directives are almost identical if you're using nginx. Open /etc/nginx/mime.types and add the following three lines inside your types {}declaration (in recent versions of nginx they're already there):***

```
text/x-component htc;
application/x-shockwave-flash swf;
image/svg+xml svg;
```

Comment: Glad you found a solution, I completely forgot about the `mime.types` file.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this..

```
location = /border-radius.htc {
  default_type 'text/x-component';
  try_files $uri /border-radius.htc;
}
```

Note the actual file location is relative to your `root` path.

Comment: Marco, your kinda/sorta looks like CSS, but what is `location` ?  I dont understand that syntax.

Comment: Take a look at [location matching](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location) and [default_type](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#default_type). The former is allows you to set different properties based on the request URL, such as a different root path or in this case, a different mime type. Other common uses for location matching are rewrites and reverse proxies.