# Compass and PIE don't seem to work

Tags: css, internet-explorer, compass-sass, sass, css3pie

I'm using [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) to create webpage CSS styles. I wanna use CSS3 features like `border-radius` and `linear-gradient` but Internet Explorer refuses to cooperate.

I coded it this way:

```
$pie-behavior: url("../stylesheets/PIE.htc");
// I've tried 'stylesheets/PIE.htc' and '/pink/stylesheets/PIE.htc' (all webpage is in folder 'pink').
$pie-base-class: pie-base;

.pie-base {
  @include pie-element(relative);
}

body {
  @include pie;
  @include background(
      image-url('header_background.png') no-repeat top center,
      linear-gradient(top center,
        $bg-gradient-start, $bg-gradient-stop
      ) no-repeat,
      image-url('wavy-white.jpg')
    );
}
```

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that cssPIE don't understand `rgba` values so my idea of making gradient from colour to transparent shouldn't work :/ Also IE don't understand inline SVG in CSS styles so even that feature isn't working. So only way is to make another style for IE and delete gradients from all gradiented elements :/

Answer (score 3):

My test methodology would be:

**1/** Is `PIE.htc` found by IE? [PIE documentation](http://css3pie.com/documentation/getting-started/) states that:

> Note: this path is relative to the HTML file being viewed, not the CSS file it is called from.

In order to verify if the directory indicated in your Compass file is OK, you can add an image in the same directory and try to display it as an HTML image, something like:

```
<body><div>
  <img src="stylesheets/yourtestimage.png" alt="If you can read this, it failed" width="400" height="400">
</div></body>
```

It should then be clear if this directory is the good one or not :)

**2/** Then try some simple CSS rule with no Compass code, in order to avoid problems that could be caused by Compass and not involving PIE. Example :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <title>PIE and border-radius</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    p {
        width: 400px;
        height: 100px;
        line-height: 100px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: center;
        color: yellow;
        background-color: darkgreen;
        border-radius: 5px 6px 7px 8px;
        pie-border-radius: 30px; /* shouldn't be necessary but just in case ... Please test with and without this prefixed property */
        behavior: url(***/PIE.htc);
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>this paragraph should be rounded in lesser IE</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**3/** Add other CSS3 instructions one by one, still in CSS with no Compass code. `background` won't be parsed by PIE, you must use -pie-background (not sure if your Compass generates that?).
First a simple linear gradient with no multiple background:

```
p {
  /* (...) */
  -pie-background: linear-gradient(#F44, #400); /*PIE*/
  /* (...) */
}
```

Then multiple background:

```
p {
  /* (...) */
  -pie-background: url(***/small_or_transparent_image1.png) left top no-repeat,
                   url(***/repeating_image2.png) left top repeat,
                   darkgreen;
  /* (...) */
}
```

and finally a mix:

```
p {
  /* (...) */
  -pie-background: url(***/small_or_transparent_image1.png) left top no-repeat,
                   linear-gradient(#F44, #400),
                   darkgreen;
  /* (...) */
}
```

BTW, is your multibackground successfully displayed on Firefox and webkit browsers with -moz-linear-gradient and so on? The [generator from Colorzilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) can help you with all this prefixes (and for the next step with Compass, it happens to support its format via "switch to scss", in case you didn't already know).

**4/** Then add variables and scss code in your Compass file. I can't help you there, I use LESS or plain CSS. You should check the generated CSS against your Compass code: does the latter generate the CSS you intended it to generate?

Answer (score 1):

I have found that cssPIE is tricky to work with.  When I set it up, I used the js implementation instead of the htc implementation:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8 ]>
  <script src="/js/libs/PIE.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Here is my real world example:  http://www2.highpoint.edu/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a proper MIME type in your .htaccess ?
Like so :

```
AddType text/x-component htc
```

Comment: Yes, I've chcecked it by `curl -I http://localhost/pink/stylesheets/PIE.htc` and I've got `Content-Type: text/x-component`. Also I'm using Nginx, not Apache.

Comment: maybe check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138464/how-to-configure-htc-files-to-work-on-nginx

Comment: Unfortanetly: `$ cat /etc/nginx/conf/mime.types | grep htc` produces `text/x-component htc;`